# Winter deraillers

Tags: gears, winter

I commute all Winter long on my Winter bike and I realize I don't use many gears.  The back derailleur gets jammed with salt, dirt and other debris.  I'd like to build a bike with fix gear at the back and two at the front.  Any ideas, suggestion or comments?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Unfortunately, an open-ended question like this is [too broad](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for our Q&A format. Please see our [help center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) or take our [tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about what questions fit well within our framework.

Comment: how often do you clean it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rear wheel with an internal 3 speed hub (you can get more gears if you like) should solve the problem you are having.  The gearing system is kept enclosed and away from salt and dirt. It's a little expensive as you basically have to buy a new rear wheel, or relace your old one, but this is the best way to fix it. That or go completely single speed.

Comment: As an additional point: if one would use only a triple chain blade and a single speed sprocket at the rear one would still need some chain tensioner mechanism to compensate the different chain lengths. This part would quite likely be in the salt again.

Comment: If you don't have horizontal or semi-horizontal dropouts, you may still need a chain tensioner with an IGH, but they are much more simple, and some have [no moving parts](http://www.derailedonline.com/archives/000024.html) and therefore have fewer problems.